# I have installed Android Studio Flamingo on my 22.04 LTS Ubuntu System, but after installation application is not shown any where

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, software-uninstall, android-studio, ubuntu-for-android

I have installed Android Studio Flamingo on my 22.04 LTS Ubuntu System, but after installation application is not shown any where. I have installed flutter on my system. Don't know what to do?